# Script bulk folder creation in Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-2010

I need to create a some folders in every single mailbox in our exchange organisation.

Is there a quick way to achieve this with a powershell script?

(note this is *not* public folders, these folders must exist inside the users mailbox)

Comment: Pretty sure this is a duplicate, but I am not finding the question that I remember seeing a while back.

Comment: @Zoredache - same, and my search skills aren't too bad these days. Unfortunately everything I found was prefixed with the word "public" as in public folders.

Comment: I haven't played with it since I don't have 2010 yet, but ExFolders may be able to do something.  http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2009/12/04/3408943.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with the Exchange Web Services (EWS) API. This script *should* create a folder in a mailbox (I don't have an E2K10 machine w/ EWS 1.1 installed handy right now so I'm cobbling this together from code samples and memory and hoping it'll actually work-- it looks right). This should work as the basis for a script to iterate through mailboxes creating folders (but since I'm such a PowerShell dunce I'm leaving that up to you):

```
$MailboxName = "mailbox@domain.com"

$dllpath = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\1.0\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll"
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($dllpath)
$service = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::Exchange2007_SP1)

$windowsIdentity = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
$sidbind = "LDAP://<SID=" + $windowsIdentity.user.Value.ToString() + ">"
$aceuser = [ADSI]$sidbind

$service.AutodiscoverUrl($aceuser.mail.ToString())

$folderid = new-object  Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Root, $MailboxName)
$RootFolder = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($service, $folderid)

$NewFolder = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder($service)
$NewFolder.DisplayName = "Folder_to_Create"
$NewFolder.Save($RootFolder.Id.UniqueId)
```

This script assumes you've got EWS 1.1 installed and are logged-on with a credential that has permission to access the subject mailbox.

Comment: EWS is certainly installed on some of the servers, because it's being used integration with an external system. I'll give it a go, thanks.